# want to show product items into shopping cart using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**I am trying to show items  on shopping cart but facing some error, how to fix it ?**

> Non-static method Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart::add() should not be
>   called statically https://flareapp.io/share/w5BGAXm8#F43

**Controller**

```
public function cart()
{
   $cart_list = Cart::Content();
   $cart_data = [];
    foreach($cart_list as $cart){
     $cart_data [] = [
     'product_name' => $cart->product_name,
     'product_image' => $cart->product_image,
     'qty' => $cart->qty,
     'product_price' => $cart->product_price,
     ];
   }
     return view('front_end/cart')->with(compact(['cart_data']));
 }


public function addcart(Request $request){
     $productId=$request->id;
     $productById = DB::table('products')->where('id', $productId)->first(); // Get all 
       Cart::add([
                 'id'=>  $productId,
                 'product_name'=>$productById->product_name,
                 'product_price'=>$productById->product_price,
                 'qty'=>$request->qty,
                 'product_image'=>$productById->product_image,
                ]);
   return redirect('/cart');
```

Comment: Cart is modal or another library...

Comment: Where did you define variable `$cart`?

Comment: Could you add the code where you import `Cart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public function cart()
{
    return view('frontend/cart');
}

public function addCart(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->id);

    $cartItem = Cart::add([
         'id' => $product->id,
         'name' => $product->name,
         'qty' => $request->qty,
         'price' => $product->price,
     ]);

     Cart::associate($cartItem->rowId, 'App\Product');

     return redirect()->route('cart');
}
```

Using the associate() method, you are telling the cart that an item in it is associated with the Product model.

Then in your view, you can do this:

```
@foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
    // your code here
    // but try to access your values as $item->rowId, $item->name, $item->qty, $item->price

@endforeach
```

Then for the product image, you can do this:

```
<img src="{{ asset($item->model->image) }}" alt="product">
```

Comment: I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Please keep in mind that you use the name of the keys as required i.e. `id`, `name`, `qty`, and `price` as described [here](https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart#usage)

Comment: how to fix this error  ?    Call to undefined function Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\array_get()   https://flareapp.io/share/NPLZ345w#F46

Comment: Seems you're using Laravel 6 which the Shopping Cart package doesn't support yet. I would suggest you follow the instructions from the official docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers).

Comment: Or you could make a few tweaks directly to the package by finding it in the `vendor`. In the `src/CartItem.php`, you can replace all instances of `array_get()` with `\Arr::get()`

Comment: where can i replace array_get()  ?

Comment: `vendor/gloudemans/Shoppingcart/src/CartItem.php`

Comment: i used this library use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
 now it's working thanks Abiobla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203303/discussion-between-abiola-and-zubair-mukhtar).

Answer (score 0):

**Use `create` method**

```
  Cart::create([
                 'id'=>  $productId,
                 'product_name'=>$productById->product_name,
                 'product_price'=>$productById->product_price,
                 'qty'=>$request->qty,
                 'product_image'=>$productById->product_image,
                ]);
   return redirect('/cart');
```

Comment: Hope its Work!!!!

Comment: Please select this answer if it is help for you THANK YOU